# Как работают доменные алиасы?

Tags: dns

Допустим сайт расположен по адресу site.com. Купили домен st.com и прописали его алиасом к основному адресу. пользователь перешел по адресу st.com, что он увидит в адресной строке?

Comment: в адресной строке будет st.com, контент страницы же зависет от того, как на сервере настроено, что будет отдавать при определенном домене.

Comment: @tcpack4, а локалсторадж и кукисторадж для каждого имени будут свои?

Comment: да, для каждого свои

Comment: можно в mod_rewrite написать редирект на старый адрес если пользователь заходит на новый, тогда куки и прочее будет от старого домена

Comment: @ГеннадийП, а урл при этом будет какой?

Comment: с редиректом поменяется на site.com

Answer (score 1):

Если вы говорите о добавлении записи типа CNAME, которая должна ссылаться на уже существующую запись типа А, то ответом будет: Вы увидите страницу, которую web-сервер, расположенный по IP-адресу А-записи, возвращает для неизвестных страниц (страницу по-умолчанию).

Дело в том что ваш браузер сначала определяет ip-адрес ресурса (при этом использует записи dns), затем отправляет запрос http на этот ip-адрес. В запросе http указывается к какому сайту этот запрос (ведь на сервере может быть много сайтов). Получая запрос, сервер дает ответ согласно запрошенной информации. Если сервер не знает что должен делать при получении какого-то запроса (не имеет в конфигурации точных инструкций) то скорее всего отдаст то что назначено для отдачи по умолчанию. Возможно это будет нужный вам сайт, а может быть реклама хостера или еще что-нибудь.

Именно настройки web-сервера и содержимое сайта формируют картинку для пользователя. В том числе один и тот же сайт может показываться по разным адресам.